# What is the priority of the messages which are retried under maxReceiveCount (dead-letter queue)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a FIFO SQS queue that triggers a lambda and when the lambda function is successful, it will automatically remove the message in the FIFO queue, but when the lambda fails it sends the message to dead-letter queue before maxReceiveCount.Where the maxReceiveCount is set to 3. So the failed message will retry thrice before sending it to the dead-letter queue, But as it's a FIFO queue will it complete the 3 retries for the message and then move on to the next messages? What is the priority order of execution for the messages with maxReceiveCount > 0.

Reference - [maxReceiveCount - Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SetQueueAttributes.html)

Comment: Is the lambda doing `sendMessage` to the DLQ, or are you using the `maxReceiveCount` to automatically send failed messages?

Comment: I would expect the lambda to retry to the one message that fails over and over until it is sent to a DLQ before it can work on any other message within the same group. Meaning that the receiveCount should not have an effect on any priority.

Comment: @Tobin using the default SQS maxReceiveCount to handle that and send to DLQ

Comment: @luk2302 but the `maxReceiveCount` is on the SQS side, So are you sure the SQS will send the same message to lambda until the retry count is maxed out? or is that your assumption?

Comment: I am pretty sure because everything else would defeat the purpose of a FIFO queue entirely.

Answer (score 1):

A FIFO queue *guarantees strict ordering of messages* and retries do not affect this property. Therefore **SQS will not deliver any subsequent messages until the current one is either deleted (processed) or moved to the DLQ**.

To quote the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues-understanding-logic.html) (emphasis mine):

> If the consumer detects a failed ReceiveMessage action, it can retry as many times as necessary, using the same receive request attempt ID. Assuming that the consumer receives at least one acknowledgement before the visibility timeout expires, **multiple retries don't affect the ordering of messages**.

Just below that it explicitly states:

> When you receive a message with a message group ID, no more messages for the same message group ID are returned unless you delete the message or it becomes visible.